# How to calculate $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{2\pi(1 - 2x_1)}{|2\pi x + \hat{\pi}|^4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Consider the series

$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2\pi(1 - 2x)}{(2\pi x + \pi)^4}.$$

This series converges to $\frac{\pi}{12}$ as can be seen in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20-infinity%20to%20infinity%20(2pi*(1%20-%20%202x))%2F((2*pi*x%20%2B%20pi)%5E4)) . Now instead of a scalar $x$ I would like to consider instead a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and calculate the value of

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{2\pi(1 - 2x_1)}{|2\pi x + \hat{\pi}|^4},$$

where $\hat{\pi} = [\pi, \pi]^T$. So this could be viewed as a generalization of the previous summation to two dimensions.

How can the value that this series converges to be calculated?

Comment: What is the absolute value of a vector?

Comment: And I suppose WolframAlpha computed the first limit by expanding the quartic, and solving the series for each individual term. You might try the same approach here.

Comment: Pulling out the $\pi$ factor,
$$ -\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(2x-1)}{(2x+1)^4}=-\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)^4}+\frac{-3-2n}{(2n+1)^4} \right)$$
equals
$$ \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} =\frac{8}{\pi^3}\left(\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta(4)\right)=\frac{8}{\pi^3}\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdot\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\frac{\pi}{12}.$$

Comment: @TMM In the second series we are taking the magnitude of the vector.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, very nice to see how you evaluated that! Have you any ideas for the second one?

Comment: @sonicboom: that is less trivial but still has a nice closed form (just see below). Are you confident with Dirichlet series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling out the $\pi$ factor,
$$ -\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(2x-1)}{(2x+1)^4}=-\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)^4}+\frac{-3-2n}{(2n+1)^4} \right)$$
equals
$$ \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} =\frac{8}{\pi^3}\left(\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta(4)\right)=\frac{8}{\pi^3}\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdot\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\frac{\pi}{12}.$$
In a similar way, the second series equals
$$ \frac{16}{\pi^3}\sum_{x\geq 0}\sum_{y\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left((2x+1)^2+(2y+1)^2\right)^2}$$
that is deeply related with a Dirichlet series. It is:
$$ \frac{16}{\pi^3}\cdot\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\ n\equiv 2\!\pmod{\!\!4}}}\!\!\!\!\!\! \frac{r_2(n)}{n^2}$$
where $r_2(n)$ stands for the number of ways for writing $n$ as a sum of two squares.
 Its explicit value is given by:
$$ \frac{7\sinh(\pi)\,\zeta(3)-\pi^3}{4 \pi ^2 (1+\cosh\pi)}. $$
That can be achieved through the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: Thanks again, I am not experienced with Dirichlet series, I will have to look them up. I haven't needed to work with series so much but now that I'm dealing with biperiodic lattices they are appearing everywhere. What initial step are you taking to split the series from $$ -\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(2x-1)}{(2x+1)^4}$$ into $$-\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)^4}+\frac{-3-2n}{(2n+1)^4} \right)$$

Comment: Exactly, the preliminary steps involve a reduction to the first quadrant.

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure what mapping is being used to change from $x$ to $n$ when you split the summation into two separate summation. I imagined it was simply $x \to n$ for $x >0$ and $x \to -n$ for $x < 0$ but that would give $$-\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{n \ge 0} \bigg( \frac{(2n - 1)}{(2n + 1)^4} +  \frac{(-2n - 1)}{(1 - 2n)^4}\bigg).$$ So how did you get your expression?